# javascript logical operator as argument in function

Tags: javascript

i am reading a book about build web app with node, backbone and mongodb. i got samples from book and encounter a code snippet, that confused me.

```
  var login = function(email, password, callback) {
    var shaSum = crypto.createHash('sha256');
    shaSum.update(password);
    Account.findOne({email:email,password:shaSum.digest('hex')},function(err,doc){
      callback(null!=doc);
    });
  };
```

look at argument of callback function null!=doc, i know that in javascript is mean null not equal doc, but how come that you can use it in as argument.

Comment: `null!=doc` gets evaluated as a boolean and the result is passed to the callback, that's all. It's the same as having `var docIsNull = null!=doc; callback(docIsNull);`

Comment: ^^^^^ What he said, evaluating an expression returns a boolean, wether or not that evaluation happens in a seperate variable or directly does'nt matter, it still passes the resulting boolean to the callback function.

Comment: @Ian: your comment should be accepted as answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

`null!=doc` gets evaluated as a boolean and the result is passed to `callback`, that's all.

It's the same as having:

```
var docIsNull = null!=doc;
callback(docIsNull);
```

I'm not sure of the specific method's result, but it's just providing the callback with a `true` or `false`, whether the `doc` value was `null` or not.

I would guess that if `doc` were `null`, that means that specific email, with that specific password, wasn't found. So when you're calling `login`, you'd probably use:

```
login("some email", "some password", function (authenticated) {
    if (authenticated) {
        // email/password found and matched
    } else {
        // no match
    }
});
```

Comment: @user1743843 No problem! Does that make sense and help?

Answer (score -2):

It seems that was is going on is as follows. When that function is called that nul is inheriting a true value from doc and then this is used in the processing of the call back function. what's happening here is that when null is said not to be equal to doc that the call back function will be processed knowing that null is NOT equal to doc. If we knew more about the function and what is going on I could be more elaborative but as of now all I can say is exactly what is happening.

Comment: This is completely wrong. `null` is a keyword and primitive value in JavaScript.